# How to Link between Stoichiometry, Energy Content of a Fuel, Combustion in a Cylinder-Piston, and Otto-Cycle, Compression Ratio, & Thermal Efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: Engine Geometry]

[image: Otto Cycle]

Picture 2, [source](https://www.mechanicalbooster.com/2017/10/otto-cycle.html):

I would like to do a real calculation of a piston. Below is data of my Toyota car engine 2NR-VE's geometry, 4 cylinder but in this case I take only one cylinder:

- Total cylinder capacity = 1496cc, so capacity of one cylinder = 374cc,
- Bore size = 7.25 cm,
- Compression Ratio (CR) = 11.5:1,
- Cylinder height (h) = 9.06 cm,

Calculation:

1. From the volume and the bore size we know that the 9.06cm is the total height of the cylinder, not the bore size as written in their website.
2. From the Bore size: Annulus (A) = 41.28cm^2,
3. From the compression ratio (CR) and Bore Size (A), --> the stroke = 7.79cm, and the clearance = 1.27cm,
4. The Displacement (D) = A * Stroke  = 41.28cm^2*7.79cm = 321.57cc,
5. From the cylinder volume with assumption that Oxygen=21%, oxygen is 78.54cc = 0.07854L,
6. From internet (not official, but just consider it be so.) I got that the fuel's IUPAC is C10H24 and the Calorific Value is 44.2MJ/kg and its density = 0.723 (kg/L), then the calorific value = 31.96MJ/L,
7. From the stoichiometry, C10H24 + 16O2 --> 10CO2 + 12H2O.
   Calculating the required C10H24 at NTP which gas occupy 24.0548L volume, then moles of Oxygen at NTP = 0.07854L/(24.0548L/mole) = 0.003265 moles = 3.265mmoles.
8. Since the reaction requires 16 moles of O2 for every mole C10H24, then:
   Moles of C10H24 = Moles of Oxygen/16 = 0.003265moles/16 = 0.000204 moles = 0.204mmoles,
9. That 0.000204 moles C10H24 converted to liter at STP = 0.000204L*24.0548L/mole = 0.00491L = 4.91mL=4.91cc.
10. As in the point 6, the calorific value of that fuel = 31.96MJ/L, then calorie of every combustion = 156.91kJ.

My questions:

1. Where is the combustion occurs in the Otto P-V diagram? At point 2?
2. Is that calculations from step 1 to step 10 correct?
3. How that stoichiometry linked to the thermal efficiency of that engine? In the formula I read the thermal efficiency is not related to geometry.
4. Is it valid to use NTP for that calculation? NTP: 20 degree Celsius and 1 ATM, as fuel is not gas, it is liquid which boiling point is 204 degree Celsius, is.

Comment: Read some books by Judge: https://www.amazon.com/Speed-Diesel-Engines-Arthur-William/dp/0412010801, Chapman: https://www.amazon.com/Modern-High-Speed-Oil-Engines/dp/B001KJYU74, Cummins: https://octanepress.com/book/diesels-engine. Then books like Engineering Thermodynamics Work and Heat Transfer will also cover the theory you need.

Comment: I am talking about Otto cycle, not the Diesel.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do some reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_cycle

Comment: Of course I did some reading, including using chatGPT a lot to understand that question, especially about that efficiency. Thermal efficiency is something different. Two of my reading is here: https://www.mechanicalbooster.com/2017/10/otto-cycle.html, and here: https://www.thermal-engineering.org/what-is-otto-cycle-otto-engine-definition/. But there is gamma or sometimes denoted as k, which it is not in the stoichiometry's calculation.

Comment: So what is gamma?

Comment: k or gamma is heat capacity, and it is a constant or a property that specific belong to every substance.

Comment: @SolarMike, what do you think with my stoichiometry's calculation? Is it true? For single piston will consume 4.91cc for every combustion. With four piston, it will consume 19.64cc. According to what I got from internet, my tire's diameter is 16", converted to cm it is 40.64cm or 40.64m==>Circumference = pi*d=1.2767m. If I drive my car constant at 3000rpm, then my car will combust 1500 times/minute, which will consume 4.91cc/piston*4 piston*1500rpm=29,460cc/minute or 29.6L/minute and will travel/minute 1.2767m*3000=3.83km. Impossible consume so high fuel. Something wrong with that calculation.

Comment: gamma is the ratio of the heat capacities for a given gas. For air it is about 1.4

Comment: @GregLocock, where to find the cp and the cv? As I read, gamma is cp/cv.

Comment: A book of thermodynamic tables is your best bet, I used to use Thermodynamic Tables In SI (Metric) Units
METRIC UNITS
By: R.W. Haywood (Editor)   but as i said it differs for each gas, so the exhaust will be different to the incoming air, and the fuel/air mixture.

Comment: @GregLocock, thank you for your info. Btw, what do you think about the stoichiometric calculation, is it correct? Mean, I need 4.91cc fuel for every combustion/cylinder for 374cc cylinder volume. It is also my concern.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't checked your calculations.

Comment: Redo your fuel calculation using the mass of air and the mass of fuel - 1kg of fuel will need 14.7kg of air. Density of air is about 1.12kg/m^3 so your calculations are way off. see https://x-engineer.org/air-fuel-ratio/

Comment: @SolarMike, have you ever think how many liters your consumes fuel in idle/stationary condition? Idle/stationary means, you turn your car on without turning any other such AC, and you let it be so. My car's idle rpm is 750rpm. First, calculate consumption per cylinder, then multiply by number of your car's cylinder, then count per minute and then divide by 2 as combustion occurs every rotation, and then multiply by 60 to get 1 hour. I calculated the fuel consumption, I put 40.1micoL/combustion/cylinder. I found it is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the combustion occurs in the Otto P-V diagram? At point 2?

Yes

> Is that calculations from step 1 to step 10 correct?

Maybe, but what are you trying to accomplish?  It looks fine on the surface.

> How that stoichiometry linked to the thermal efficiency of that engine? In the formula I read the thermal efficiency is not related to geometry.

You read the wrong formula, theoretical thermal efficiency of the otto cycle is strictly related to the compression ratio.

> Is it valid to use NTP for that calculation? NTP: 20 degree Celsius and 1 ATM, as fuel is not gas, it is liquid which boiling point is 204 degree Celsius, is.

Calculating combustion requires taking inlet conditions and compressing/heating up the combustion components from there.  It still isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Note that a huge amount of your combustion energy goes out the exhaust.

Comment: There is one more question that I forget to ask. As the requires fuel for single combustion per cylinder is 4.91cc, mean the 4-cylinder require 19.64cc.  As my car stationary/idle at 750rpm where combustion occurs every 2 rpm the crankcase, means that with the car just idle it will burn 19.64cc*(750 rpm/2) = 7,365cc or around 7.4L. This is weird. It is just when idle.